# Cannot install 16.04 LTS (x86), "task mapper/0:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds"

Tags: system-installation

I have a handful of old (XP-era) machines to be donated and I'm installing (or trying to) Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (x86) on them. I've had no problems with any of the machines until now. It's a Compaq Presario 2100 laptop with a Celeron M processor @ 2.4GHz, 512MB RAM, and 80GB hard drive. It runs fine with a clean install of XP SP3 so I'm pretty sure there's no hardware issue here.

The problem is this: I boot from the Ubuntu installer, it throws up the purple screen, then after awhile I get what appears to be a kernel panic with the same three lines:

```
[#####.######] INFO: task swapper/0.1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[#####.######]       Not tainted 4.15.0-45 generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[#####.######] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

...where "[#####.######]" is an always-increasing numeric value. These three lines repeat themselves apparently forever.

I have a bootable USB flash drive with the Ubuntu installer on it which has worked on the last five machines without complaint. I burned the same ISO to a DVD and tried again but got the same problem. I've reset the BIOS to default values, also no effect.

What's going on here, and how can I get Ubuntu onto this machine?

**EDIT:** I just discovered that the minimum requirements include 1.5GB RAM, which may be the issue. One other PC I set up with this release has only 1GB and it installed/works without issue, but this one at 512MB may just be too little. Gonna find more RAM and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may find this in the future...

The issue is almost definitely memory-related, which is to say there's not enough memory to install Ubuntu 16 on this machine. Furthermore, this particular laptop maxes out at 1GB RAM so I can't install Ubuntu 16 no matter what as it requires 1.5GB RAM. I *am* able to install Lubuntu 16 on this machine without difficulty so that's what I'm doing.